# NetworkError: 503 Service Unavailable Django PostgreSQL

Tags: python, database, django, postgresql, heroku

I have an app written with Django back-end in Heroku.

I'm using Heroku Postgres.

Some time ago, I deleted a user from my DB, and now, every time I want to access Userprofile from admin I get this:

```
"NetworkError: 503 Service Unavailable - http://app.herokuapp.com/admin/backend/userprofile/"
```

Any ideas on what can I do to solve this?

**PS:**

I'm using OS X 10.9.2 (Mavericks)

Comment: Look at the log files.

Comment: Log doesn't show anything at all. That's strange. I've tried with console from Chrome and firebug in Firefox

Comment: I know the fail is because when accessing userprofile in DB, when it tries to load the userprofile with a user that no longer exists it throws this fail. I'm at point 0 of managing DB, so I have no clue where to start looking or what to look in order to get into the DB and delete the failing userprofile

Comment: Look at the *heroku* log files for PostgreSQL and for your app. See the Heroku manual for how to get them.

Comment: Didn't know that existed, as I said, I know 0 from DB. Thanks for the tip. I'll post here what the log says if I can't solve it quickly. Thanks @CraigRinger